# DataReader for Table Valued Parameter in VB.Net does not work

Tags: sql-server-2012, vb.net-2010, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to use DataReader object retrieving data from a text file and use it as a source for table valued parameter of a stored procedure (SQL Server 2012).
The procedure works fine when I try it within SQL Server (SSMS), text file data is retrieved into DataReader without problems but command cannot be executed.
Here's a piece of my code:

```
        Dim oInsertCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.proc_load_file", oSqlConn)
    oInsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    Dim oTVPar As SqlClient.SqlParameter = oInsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoadRM", oReader)

    oTVPar.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured

    oInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error message is: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The data for table-valued parameter "@LoadRM" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter."
The statement has been terminated." The error occures in thw last code line posted here.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Its expecting a table. You are passing a data reader?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing DataReader as it is the MS example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx
Steraming Rows With DataReader

Comment: Yep you are right. I never used this approach. Try passing a datatable as outlined in one of the other examples.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion. Need to find a way to retrieve text file data into DataTable :-)

Comment: If are doing this via reader, should be a small change to become a data table. I think there is a fill function. Or maybe that needs a data adapter, dont remember exactly. In any case try this approach and publish your results here.

Comment: Resolved the problem. The order of fields in select command (not posted) was not exactly the same as order of columns of TVP, thus characters count exceeded the limit.

Thanks for your interest and help Neolisk.